# Conditional summing in Pyomo

Tags: python, conditional-statements, pyomo

I'm trying to reduce the number of binary variables I need in a Big-M reformulation from a linear number to a logarithmic one. I have the following equation:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVMXg.png) (for i = 1, ..., m)

Here, h<sup>i</sup> are known vectors where each element has a binary value. z<sub>j</sub> are unknown binary variables.

So, if h<sup>i</sup> = z the constraint is enforced.

What I was wondering is, is there a way to code these conditional sums in Pyomo?

I know that in Mosel we can use the '|' operator to add conditions but was unable to find something similar for Pyomo. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a couple ways to do this, but the below gets the job done w/ no additional variables and just a little "examination" of `h` inside of the constraint construction.  Bringing `h` "inside" the model is optional, but I think good practice.

#### Code

```
# big M with vector

# making a big-M constraint from a vector matching operation

import pyomo.environ as pyo

big_m = 11

h = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.I = pyo.Set(initialize=[0, 1])
m.J = pyo.Set(initialize=[0, 1, 2])

m.z = pyo.Var(m.J, domain=pyo.Binary)
m.x = pyo.Var()

m.h = pyo.Param(m.I, domain=pyo.Any, initialize=h)
m.A = pyo.Param(m.I, initialize=[2, 3])
m.b = pyo.Param(m.I, initialize=[4, 5])

@m.Constraint(m.I)
def big_m(m, i):
    # make a couple subsets of J on-the-fly
    ones = {idx for idx, value in enumerate(m.h[i]) if value==1}
    zeros = m.J.difference(ones)
    
    # build the "enforcement" summation
    enforce = len(ones) - sum(m.z[j] for j in ones) + sum(m.z[j] for j in zeros)

    # use it
    return m.A[i] * m.x <= m.b[i] + enforce * big_m
    
m.big_m.pprint()

# set some values to see the constraint evaluated... (simulate solving)
m.z.set_values({0:1, 1:0, 2:1})
m.x.set_value(1.5)

m.big_m.display()
```

##### Output:

```
big_m : Size=2, Index=I, Active=True
    Key : Lower : Body                                      : Upper : Active
      0 :  -Inf : 2*x - (4 + (2 - (z[0] + z[2]) + z[1])*11) :   0.0 :   True
      1 :  -Inf :   3*x - (5 + (1 - z[2] + z[0] + z[1])*11) :   0.0 :   True
big_m : Size=2
    Key : Lower : Body  : Upper
      0 :  None :  -1.0 :   0.0
      1 :  None : -11.5 :   0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

In Pyomo, you can implement this constraint using a conditional expression in a Constraint object.

Here how you can do it  :

> ```
> from pyomo.environ import *
> ```
>
> m = ... # the number of elements in hi
>
> model = ConcreteModel() model.hi = Var(range(m), within=Binary)
> model.z = Var(range(m), within=Binary)
>
> def conditional_sum(model, i):
> return (model.hi[i] == 1) <= (model.z[i] == 1)
>
> model.con = Constraint(range(m), rule=conditional_sum)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but shouldn't `hi` be a parameter and not a variable since we know its value? 
What I was trying before is:
`hi = {}
hi[1] = (0,0)
hi[2] = (0,1)
hi[3] = (1,1)
hi[4] = (1,0)`

`model.hi = Param(hi.keys(), initialize = hi)`

Seems like this way, I would end up adding additional binary variables.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. In your code, "hi" should be defined as a parameter since its values are known. The code you provided defines "hi" as a parameter with keys 1, 2, 3, and 4, and assigns corresponding values of (0,0), (0,1), (1,1), and (1,0) respectively. This way, you would not end up adding additional binary variables.

Comment: this isn't legal `pyomo` code.  You can't do logical testing on a variable inside of a constraint.